# Newton's laws of motion in kinematics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I know that there are 3 laws of motion given by Newton, but are there any other laws which govern the motion of the bodies?

Comment: It seems to me that you're implicitly assuming that Newton's laws are insufficient to fully describe motion, could you explain why that is?

Comment: It's not that I'm implicitly assuming but I'm asking the possibility of inability of laws of motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three laws of Newton basically tell you about the **movement** of bodies that have a **mass** if a **force** acts on them.

There are two ways to answer your question based on this.

1. Newton's laws don't work if the bodies move at *very high speed* (you'd need laws from Special Relativity for this), or if the masses involved are very large (this is the realm of General Relativity) or if you get to very small scales (Quantum Mechanics). So, in these special extreme cases, Newton's laws are not sufficient (in fact wrong) and you need other laws to describe motion.
2. Nothing is said in Newton's laws about what the force is. Depending on the context you might need additional laws such as the law of gravity, Coulomb law, Lorentz force,... in order to do calculations using Newton's laws.

Also, there are alternative ways to describe motion such as the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian mechanics, which can replace Newton's laws.